# Convergence Proof: Difference within Function of Epsilon

Tags: limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Here's the problem, and then my proposed proof:

> Suppose that $\phi : (0, \infty) \mapsto (0, \infty)$ is a function such that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\phi(\epsilon) = 0.$ Let $a_1,a_2,\dots$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that this sequence converges to $a$ if and only if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that for $n > N$, we have $|a_n-a|\leq \phi(\epsilon).$

(from Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms (Hubbard and Hubbard))

My proof is for the first statement (the if, not the only if).

---

First, to avoid confusion, the argument of the function $\phi$ will be renamed to $\epsilon'$.By the definition of the limit, the statement that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\phi(\epsilon) = 0$ is the same as saying that $$\forall\epsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ such that } |\epsilon'| \leq \delta \implies |\phi(\epsilon')| \leq \epsilon $$

By assumption, $|a_n - a| \leq \phi(\epsilon')$, and from the statement above, we get

$$|a_n - a| \leq \phi(\epsilon') \leq \epsilon$$
We want $\phi(\epsilon') \leq \epsilon'$. However, since it must be true for all $\epsilon$ and all $\epsilon'$ greater than 0, the two can be taken to be equal. Therefore,
$$|a_n-a| \leq \epsilon'$$

---

I'm unsure about the final step, where I say that the unprimed and primed epsilon can be taken to be equal. Is this correct?

Comment: Your proof is very good

Comment: Why do you want to conclude $|a_n-a| \leq \epsilon'$? Don't you want to show that $|a_n-a| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @md2perpe Because the argument of the function $\phi$ was renamed to $\epsilon'$. $\epsilon$ pertains to the limit of $\phi(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, not to the convergence of the sequence.

Comment: I still think that you confuse the epsilons. You want to show that if for any $\epsilon'>0$ there exists $N'$ such that for $n'>N'$ we have $|a_{n'}-a| \leq \phi(\epsilon')$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have $a_n-a| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The *if* case

#### Assumptions

1. $\lim_{\epsilon' \to 0} \phi(\epsilon') = 0$, i.e. for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\epsilon''>0$ such that for $0<\epsilon'<\epsilon''$ we have $0 \leq \phi(\epsilon')<\epsilon$
2. for any $\epsilon'>0$ there exists $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have $0 \leq |a_n−a| \leq \phi(\epsilon')$

#### To show

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$, i.e. for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have $|a_n−a| < \epsilon$

#### Proof

Take $\epsilon>0$.

By assumption 1 there exists $\epsilon''>0$ such that for all $0 < \epsilon' < \epsilon''$ we have $0 \leq \phi(\epsilon') < \epsilon$. For such $\epsilon'',$ let $\epsilon'=\epsilon''/2$. Then $0 \leq \phi(\epsilon') < \epsilon.$

By assumption 2 there now exists $N$ such that for $n > N$ we have $0 \leq |a_n-a| \leq \phi(\epsilon')$. But by the previous paragraph we have $\phi(\epsilon') < \epsilon$ so $0 \leq |a_n-a| < \epsilon$.

Thus, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for $n > N$ we have $|a_n-a| < \epsilon$.